# Reinitialization of awk variables

Tags: awk

I am struggling with resetting some awk variables. I have multiple lines of the form:
one two three ... ten

with various appearances of each word in every line. I am trying to count the number of times each word is one each line, separate from the counts from the other lines.

this is what I have so far:

```
{ for(i=length(Num); i>0; i--)

    if( Num[i] == "one" )
    {                   
            oneCount++
    }
    else if( Num[i] == "two" )
    {       
            twoCount++
    }
    else if( Num[i] == "three" )
    {
            threeCount++
    }
...
}
```

when I print out the count values, the count doesn't reinitialize with each new line. how do i fix this?

any help is much appreciated

Comment: What is `Num`? You reset all the values at the start of each loop to clear them. But this seems like the wrong approach. What are you planning to do with these counts for each line?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: Num is an array produced from using the split function because originally, the lines were of the form:
one;two;two;five;five;five

so the preceding code is: { split($1, Num, ";") }

Answer (score 1):

You seem very confused. To get a count of each field in a `;`-separated line would be:

```
awk -F';' '{
    split("",cnt)    # or "delete cnt" if using GNU awk. 
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        cnt[$i]++
    }
    for (word in cnt) {
        print word, cnt[word]
    }
}' file
```

Now is there anything else you need it to do?

Comment: this did not work for me...i was given an error that delete was illegal

Comment: then you are not using GNU awk so use `split("",cnt)` instead. I assumed you were using GNU awk since your script uses `length(array)` which is a gawk-ism.

Comment: so split($1, Num, ";", cnt)?

Comment: No. Exactly as I showed: `split("",cnt)`. That will init/empty the array `cnt[]` in any awk, just like using `delete cnt` in only GNU awk, since it is populating `cnt` with the contents of a null string. I edited my answer to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing an array in the BEGIN portion to however many variables you'd like to count. You can run a loop in the portion to clear the array at the beginning of every new line.

Alternatively, you could just reset the value of each variable to 0 or null in the portion of the program that executes every line, but I'm guessing you have many variables.

Comment: how would this work? I tried reseting to 0 but it kept giving me an error

Comment: What did you try resetting to zero? What was your exact line of code? What exact error message did you get?

Comment: how would i initialize an array in BEGIN? like BEGIN {oneCount, twoCount...} ?

i tried adding oneCount = 0 before each section of the if statement but it gave me "Syntax error"